# How do you load one angular 2 app from another angular 2 app?

Tags: java, angular, angular2-routing

I have 2 angular2 apps. I want to be able to click on a link in the first app, send some data to the server, and then load the second angular2 app from that server response. Is this possible?
I want to be able to do something like this:

Click on a link:

```
<a href="/guest-homepage">business admin</a>
```

Which calls some server code (in this case a java servlet)

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws javax.servlet.ServletException, IOException {

    RequestDispatcher req = request.getRequestDispatcher("/guest-homepage/index.html");                                            
    req.forward(request, response);
```

The /guest-homepage/index.html is the path to the second angular2 app.

When I do this now it starts over the first angular2 app instead of starting the 2nd one. How can I start the second app from the first one?

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible. In my case the tag

```
<base href>
```

in the index.html file was not set correctly. So basically because my apps are in their seperate folders, the basehref has to take into account the root of the servlet container+the folder of the app.